# cannot change text size of tabs in a tab group in Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have 3 tabs in my application. I want to adjust the size of text because if the text size is more then automatically the scroll comes in picture.

```
`var tabGroup = Ti.UI.createTabGroup();
var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({ title : "Home Page" });
var tab1 = Ti.UI.createTab({ icon : "/images/default.png", title : "Text size 1", font : { fontFamily : 'Helvetica Neue', fontSize : 8
},
window : win1
});
tabGroup.addTab(tab1);
var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({ title : "Bookmarks Page" });
var tab2 = Ti.UI.createTab({ title : "Text Size 2", icon : "/images/default.png", font : { fontFamily : 'Helvetica Neue', fontSize : 8
},
window : win2
}); tabGroup.addTab(tab2);
var win3 = Ti.UI.createWindow({ title : "Bookmarks Page" }); var tab3 = Ti.UI.createTab({ title : "Text Size 3", icon : "/images/default.png",    font : { fontFamily : 'Helvetica Neue', fontSize : 8
},
window : win3
}); tabGroup.addTab(tab3);
tabGroup.open();`
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: please check this   https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/134054/scrollabe-tabs-in-a-tab-group

you will get idea

Comment: @VRK
I don't want tab group to be scrollable and link you gave doesn't match with the query I made.
It consists of how to add scroll in tab group which is complete opposite.

Comment: in android: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/178761/titanium---android--how-to-change-the-color-of-title-text-of-tab